# Why Libgdx's Table does not accept scale action?

Tags: java, libgdx, tablelayout, scene2d

I'm using scene2d in libgdx library for creating some UI in my game.

I used a Table and I want to take some scaling action when user touches to make a button touching sense.

When I used any other "Actor" types like Group and giving it a scale action it works but not Table.

this is my Table definition:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.setSize(width, height);
table.setPosition(x, y);
table.setOrigin(width/2, height/2);
table.add(new Label(...));
table.row();
...
```

And in my touchDown event I give it a scale action:

```
table.addAction(Actions.scaleTo(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.1f));
```

And in touchUp I give it another action to get original scale:

```
table.addAction(Actions.scaleTo(1f, 1f, 0.1f));
```

As I said this code works for another types of Actors like Image and Group.
Any Ideas that why don't works for Table?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answering to my own question:

In order to the libGdx's documentation (`https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2dui#Rotation_and_scale`) table does not supports scaling and rotating if it's background was set.

If we want to scale and/or rotate the table we have to behave like the code below:

```
TextButton button = new TextButton("Text Button", skin);
Table wrapper = new Table();
wrapper.add(button);
wrapper.setTransform(true);
wrapper.setOrigin(wrapper.getPrefWidth() / 2, wrapper.getPrefHeight() / 2);
wrapper.setRotation(45);
wrapper.setScaleX(1.5f);
```

Comment: In the latest version of the library (0.9.8) `setTransform` seems to be missing, but you can instead call `setClip(true)` which enables transforming as a side effect.

Comment: @Nick - setTransform is still there under 0.9.8. It is a method of `Group` http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Group.html#setTransform%28boolean%29

Comment: Setting setTransform(true) fixed a scale on a table for me. The docs lie! They said it is true by default, but it wasn't for me :)